# Delayed 'for loop' in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, delay

I have a delayed loop working that displays the numbers 0-3 with a 1 second delay, but I want it to then start this process all over again.

I tried putting the whole code into a while loop with x<99 
(something that will never occur therefore making the loop repeat forever)
This doesn't seem to be working

Here is the code:

```
sequence=["0","1","2","3"];

while (x<99) {
x=-1;
(function myLoop (i) {          
   setTimeout(function () {   
   x++;
   document.write(sequence[x] + "<br/>");
   if (--i) myLoop(i);  
  }, 1000)
  })(4); 
}
```

[Here is a code-pen link](http://codepen.io/caedanlavneder/pen/BxyrI)

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A loop won't work in this case. There are multiple ways to do this. One would be to call `setTimeout` "recursively", increasing the index at each call.

```
var sequence=["0","1","2","3"];

(function() { // some boilerplate code to keep `i` private
    var i = 0; // running index
    (function run() {
        console.log(sequence[i]);
        i = (i+1) % sequence.length; // increase `i` and wrap around
        setTimeout(run, 1000); // next iteration
    }());
}());
```

Comment: @Caedan: You have to look at the console!

Comment: @alex23: Yeah I guess `setInterval` would work equally well. Personally I feel I have more control over the whole process when using `setInterval` with recursion. I'm also just more used to it (in combination with Ajax calls). I guess it boils down to whether you want to have the code be executed strictly every x seconds or x seconds after the last run. Might make a different in some applications.

Comment: @alex23: I read the question as that the process should run forever.

Comment: Thanks, i replaced console.log with document.write and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` comes to rescue:

"Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval